# i am trying to get the following fields from AD using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Import-Module activedirectory


$Name = "Larry Page"
$Searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn=$Name))"
[void]$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
ForEach ($User In $Results)
{
    $NTName = $User.Properties.Item("sAMAccountName")
    $CompanyName = $User.Properties.Item("company")
    $NTName + " " + $CompanyName
    [string]$userName = $NTName.properties.name
    Get-ADUser "L2371732" -Properties company,PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires

}
```

This is my code so far. I am trying to substitute $userName for L2371732 in the following line but I am getting a different error so I hard coded the username in the Get-ADUser.

I only wan the fields I specified however I am getting everything (company, distinguishedname,enabled, etc)

Comment: Is it correct that your question is how to limit the output of `Get-ADUser ...` to only the Properies described in this line? Or do I get the question wrong?

Comment: Just pipe to `Select-Object` and ask for only the props needed

Comment: why are you using the `[adsi]` stuff? all of that is built into the AD module commands ...

Comment: Get-ADUser "L2371732" | Select-Object name, emailaddress, company gives me nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying to focus on the title portion of the question.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) `-Properties` does the following:

> Specifies the properties of the output object to retrieve from the server. Use this parameter to retrieve properties that are not included in the **default set**.

So you would be seeing what you asked for in addition to the default set. If you don't want those properties you can drop the by piping to `Select-Object` and ask for only what you need.

```
$props = 'company', 'PasswordExpired', 'PasswordLastSet', 'PasswordNeverExpires'
Get-ADUser "L2371732" -Properties $props | Select-Object $props
```

If you wanted a default property returned as well e.g. samaccountname you can add that to the list with no issue.